# How to use both ng-value and ng-class without duplication?

Tags: angularjs, performance, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class, angularjs-ng-value

I have an input which uses `ng-value` with a filter to display a number.

```
<input ng-value="myDataCollection | customFilter">
```

I want to also apply `ng-class` to change the text colour to red if negative.

```
<input ng-value="myDataCollection | customFilter" ng-class="{'negative-input': (myDataCollection | customFilter) < 0}">
```

This works, but in my use case the filter has a lot of work to do to calculate the resulting value. The input is also withing a large nested `ng-repeat` so performance is a concern.

Is it possible to use `ng-class` based on the resulting value of the input as set by `ng-value` without having to run through the filter twice?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would suggest. You can directly filter the values and save it in some model variable. so it's like you will run you filter on you data collection once and then use it anywhere you want.

```
$scope.filteredData = yourFilterFunction(yourDataCollection);//this will be filtered data values

 <input ng-value="filteredData" ng-class="{ filteredData < 0 ? 'negative-input': ''}">
```

Answer (score -1):

If I am not mistaken as regards the logic you could make use of `ng-model` instead of `ng-value`.

Here's a little [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/teVA8rKKOwwKVqW04csA?p=preview) for you.